# How to route TOMCAT Manager page to a custom error page

Tags: tomcat

Thanks for helping me.

I am facing a requirement from my client, where they want to route tomcat manager page to a custom error page. So currently when accessing /manager/html with invalid credentials, it will route to a 401 unauthorized page.

My client wants to route this page to a custom error page. I wonder if this is possible. I have configured inside my TOMCAT web.xml the following.

```
<error-page>
   <error-code>400</error-code>
   <location>/error.jsp</location>
 </error-page>
 <error-page>
   <error-code>404</error-code>
   <location>/error.jsp</location>
 </error-page>
  <error-page>
   <error-code>500</error-code>
   <location>/error.jsp</location>
 </error-page>
   <error-page>
   <error-code>403</error-code>
   <location>/error.jsp</location>
 </error-page>
  <error-page>
   <error-code>401</error-code>
   <location>/error.jsp</location>
 </error-page>
  <error-page>
   <exception-type>java.lang.Throwable</exception-type>
   <location>/error.jsp</location>
 </error-page>
```

I have set for 401 to route to /error.jsp. But still the unauthorized page is displayed not my custom error page

[TOMCAT Manager page when enter invalid credentials](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ev7B8.png)

Comment: for some security reasons , I recommend you remove whole manager web application from tomcat , you never need that . you can manually deploy your application or manage them .

Comment: "_I have configured inside my TOMCAT web.xml the following_" - Be specific: what file was edited by you, and what version of Apache Tomcat is this?

Comment: A common mistake is to edit the global defaults file (the one in the `conf`) directory, instead of the one belonging to the web application (in its `WEB-INF` directory).